# Подключение к .fdb базе в Delphi

Tags: delphi, компоненты, delphi-7, база-данных, firebird

Какие компоненты нужны для подключения к `firebird` базе в `Delphi` для отображения данных таблиц в DBGrid и как они дожны быть связаны свойствами между собой?

Comment: Гуглить пробовали? [FIBPlus](http://www.devrace.com/ru/fibplus/)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov  компоненты достойные но платные.

Comment: @savro, считаете delphi7 куплена?

Comment: А почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 1):

В своих проектах я использовал [Zeos](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) компоненты для подключения к FireBird. Они сторонние но бесплатные.

Инструкция по установке находится [тут](http://mirsovetov.net/zeos-install.html)

Часть этапов подключения и связывания можно посмотреть [тут](http://mirsovetov.net/delphi-connect-mysql.html), там описывается подключение к mysql, но настройки очень близкие.

Также есть платный вариант UniDac

Answer (score 0):

Если не использовать сторонние компоненты, то

**IBDataBase** сама БД и параметры

**IBDTransaction** Транзакции

**IBSQLQuery**  запроосы

**DataSet** набор данных

Там в инспекторе свойст поймеш что с чем и как связать.

Comment: @savro я названия компонент примерно предполагал, а вот связку мне не удается сделать.

Comment: базу вяжеш с транзакциями, квери с датасетом и квери с базой.
писать в ручную не обязательно все можно сделать в инспекторе свойств.

Comment: @savro вообще-то мне нужно просто данные таблицы в `DBGrid` отобразить. Мне нужен явно для этого `IBTable`. Как его связать с вышеуказанными компонентами (извиняюсь за настырность, но очень надо)?

Comment: грид всеравно с датасетом связываать придеться, 
связка такая ИБбаза-ИБтранзакции-ИБтайбл-датасет-ДбГрид
в ИБТайбл в свйоствах прописываеш какая именно таблица нужна.

Можно без тейбла, а в квери прописать запрос к нужной таблице.

Comment: @savro вместо dataset надо использовать datasource?

Comment: datasource это источник данных указывается, то есть у грида datasource есть Датасет, а у датасета datasource есть или квери или тейбл.

Comment: ИБбаза-ИБтранзакции-ИБтайбл-датасет-ДбГрид
Да, наверное здесь имелся в виду DataSource, на месте датасет.